# Vundle: how change plugin location from ~/.vim to ~/vimfiles in Windows?

Tags: vim-windows, plugin-vundle

My home is `H:/`.

The output of `:set rtp?` gives

```
runtimepath=H:\vimfiles,H:\.vim\bundle\Vundle.vim,H:\.vim\bundle\ale,H:\.vim\bundle\SimpylFold,H:\.vim\bundle\ctrlp,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,H:\vimfiles/after,H:\vimfiles/bundle/Vundle.vim,H:\.vim\bundle\Vundle.vim/after,H:\.vim\bundle\ale/after,H:\.vim\bundle\SimpylFold/after,H:\.vim\bundle\ctrlp/after
```

This suggests that `Vundle` is searching for plugins in the `~/.vim` folder whereas I want it to search in  `~/vimfiles` folder.
I have cloned all my plugins into `~/vimfiles/plugin` because I discovered that `plugin` is a directory that will be searched for runtime files (from `:help runtimepath`).

If I leave my plugins into `~/vimfiles/plugin` generate the error of the form

```
E121: Undefined variable: g:ctrlp_ext_vars
E116: Invalid arguments for function add
```

Here is an excerpt of my `_vimrc`

```
" --- VUNDLE PLUGIN STUFF BEGIN --------
filetype off                  " required
" Vundle plugin manager
"set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/vimfiles/bundle/Vundle.vim
 call vundle#begin()
" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
" add all your plugins here (note older versions of Vundle
" used Bundle instead of Plugin)
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'dense-analysis/ale'
Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp'
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required for Vundle
" ---- VUNDLE PLUGIN STUFF END ----------
"
```

Vim version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Sep 21 2021 22:13:38)
MS-Windows 32-bit console version
Included patches: 1-3452
Compiled by appveyor@APPVYR-WIN
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl                +cscope             +iconv/dyn          +multi_lang         +smartindent        -toolbar
+arabic             +cursorbind         +insert_expand      +mzscheme/dyn       -sodium             +user_commands
+autocmd            +cursorshape        +ipv6               -netbeans_intg      +sound              +vartabs
+autochdir          +dialog_con         +job                +num64              +spell              +vertsplit
+autoservername     +diff               +jumplist           +packages           +startuptime        +virtualedit
-balloon_eval       +digraphs           +keymap             +path_extra         +statusline         +visual
+balloon_eval_term  -dnd                +lambda             +perl/dyn           -sun_workshop       +visualextra
-browse             -ebcdic             +langmap            +persistent_undo    +syntax             +viminfo
++builtin_terms     +emacs_tags         +libcall            +popupwin           +tag_binary         +vreplace
+byte_offset        +eval               +linebreak          -postscript         -tag_old_static     +vtp
+channel            +ex_extra           +lispindent         +printer            -tag_any_white      +wildignore
+cindent            +extra_search       +listcmds           +profile            +tcl/dyn            +wildmenu
+clientserver       -farsi              +localmap           +python/dyn         +termguicolors      +windows
+clipboard          +file_in_path       +lua/dyn            +python3/dyn        +terminal           +writebackup
+cmdline_compl      +find_in_path       +menu               +quickfix           -termresponse       -xfontset
+cmdline_hist       +float              +mksession          +reltime            +textobjects        -xim
+cmdline_info       +folding            +modify_fname       +rightleft          +textprop           -xpm_w32
+comments           -footer             +mouse              +ruby/dyn           -tgetent            -xterm_save
+conceal            +gettext/dyn        -mouseshape         +scrollbind         +timers
+cryptv             -hangul_input       +multi_byte_ime/dyn +signs              +title
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME\defaults.vim"
```

Comment: Don’t clone plugins from GitHub into the plugin directory. They are not the same use of the word plugin. Every file in the plugin directory on the runtimepath will be executed at vim startup. Most online plugins are structured as mini runtimepath s (*e.g.* you don’t want to execute all compiler or colorscheme scripts at startup). So you want to let Vundle manage that for you, or use something more like packages.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I changed the destination folder to `H:\vimfiles\bundle` but when I run `:PluginInstall` nothing happens in-spite Vundle claims `Done!`

Comment: I solved it by manually cloning the plugins `git clone https://github.com/tmhedberg/SimpylFold.git H:/vimfiles/bundle/SimpylFold` but I am not sure this is the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you open [vundle readme](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start), the example configuration has that info:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')
```

So I would try `call vundle#begin(':H/vimfiles/bundle')`

Comment: Tried. When I run `:PluginInstall` it goes through and it output the write `"Installing plugins to H:\vimfiles\bundle"` (that is the place where I want my plugins to be installed, I changed the destination folder due to the comment above), but nothing is cloned into `H:\vimfiles\bundle`.

Comment: I solved it by manually cloning the plugins `git clone https://github.com/tmhedberg/SimpylFold.git H:/vimfiles/bundle/SimpylFold` but I am not sure this is the right way of doing it.